# AdSense fixed-sized ad on the Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, adsense

What is the best way to place fixed-sized (i.e. 336*280) AdSense ad to the Twitter Bootstrap 3 webpage?

Say, I want the ad to be placed on the left, or right size of the `DIV`.

The remainder will be taken by the main content, and the page should stay responsive and mobile-friendly.

Comment: What is the reason that you want to use non-responsive fixed-sized ad unit in responsive Bootstrap webpage?

Answer (score 0):

For responsive design, you should use bootstrap [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).
In this [code](http://www.bootply.com/MaPzU9c5hT) you could see an example of how the bootstrap's grid system behaves.
You also could use `.pull-right` and `.pull-left` classes that behave as the css' properties `float:right` and `float:left`, respectively. If you need clear the float property you could use the `.clearfix` class.

Comment: Thank you for a very common example, iI never saw anything so useful! </sarcasm>